# Sculpting is erasing everything

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVf-UvySGqI but when I try to use the sculpt brush it just erases everything under it. Any idea how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "erases everything under it"?

Comment: It just removes everything that is under the brush, like it's digging a hole like on the picture atttached.

Comment: Are you sure you are not holding down the ctrl key while doing it. Coz although the brush is set to add, if you hold down ctrl, it will subtract. That might be the issue.

Comment: It's possible that you have inverted normals. Try checking 'Face Orientation' on the Viewport Overlays menu and see if any of the object is red. (It should be all blue.)